# How to covert PowerPoint to video or flash in php

Tags: php, flash, video, powerpoint

How to covert PowerPoint to video or flash in php? Or how would I call a process like this in unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no PHP-native method for that. But a Python commandline utility exists (which in turn *could* be called from a PHP script). It needs to invoke an OpenOffice instance over UNO. This is a significant overhead (if not already running), and probably not feasible to set up on shared hosting. But anyway, Openoffice can convert PPT files into SWF animations: 
http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter